# Getting value ifor hightly nested XML file using PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, ftp, nested, nodes

I have this XML on and FTP folder that I'm trying to get a specific value but many of the nodes are same name identified with IDs and fairly nested.

Here is a sample. ConfigData is the root. I'm trying to get the Value (enabled or disabled) for  node. Problem is that almost every node is setup Group (id)\Group (id)\Object (id Name, and Value) and there are many nodes setup that way in the XML file

```
<ConfigData>
    <Group id="ServerGrp>
        <Group id="Server.1>
            <Object id="1" Name="Enable Server" Value="Enabled"/>
        </Group>
    </Group>
</ConfigData>
```

I use this to connect to the FTP and get every object value, but can't narrow it down to the one I want.

```
$user = 'user'
$pass = 'pass'

$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient  
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pass) 

$encoder = '172.22.2.164'
$config = '/globals.xml'
$file = 'ftp://' + $encoder + $config

$xdoc = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$xdoc.load($webclient.OpenRead($file))

$nodelist = $xdoc.selectnodes("/VBrickConfigData/Group/Object")

#This will get every object value
foreach ($testCaseNode in $nodelist) {
$id = $testCaseNode.Value
    Write-Host $id
}
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking for here.  If you need to find Object nodes with a Value attribute use `Select-Xml $xdoc -XPath '//Object[@Value="Enabled"]'`

Comment: "can't narrow it down to the one I want" is more a of statement of fact than a question. If you are trying to get a specific node based on ids you know, you would use something like `"//Group[@id='ServerGrp']/Group[@id='Server.1']/Object[@id='1']"` as the XPath.

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten the syntax with the id value inside of the  node selection ("//Node[@id='id'] This worked $xdoc.SelectSingleNode("//Group[@id='ServerGrp']/Group[@id='Server.1']/Object[@id='1']").Value